# sed only removing \n provided by sed '=' command

Tags: sed, pipe, text-formatting, newlines

I created a file using:

```
printf 'this is \n not is \n is is \n this biz' > file2
```

when I try to remove all \n(newline) it only remove sed's own inserted number's newline

```
sed  '=' file2 | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

the output is:

```
 1 this is 
 2  not is 
 3  is is 
 4  this biz
```

and not what I expected which is:

```
1 this is  2  not is  3  is is  4  this biz
```

I am lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second `sed` script,

```
N
s/\n/ /
```

does not work the way you expect because it will read one line, then append the next line to it with an embedded newline inserted by the `N` command, and then replace that newline with a space (and output). When reading the line after, this result from the first two lines is discarded.

Instead, you would have had to use the hold space:

```
H;            # append to hold space with a '\n' embedded
              # for the last line:
${
    x;        # swap in the hold space
    s/\n//;   # delete the first newline (from the H command on the very first line of input)
    y/\n/ /;  # replace all other newlines with spaces
    p;        # print result
}
```

This script is running once for each line of input, collecting data in the hold space until we hit the last line. At the last line, we process the collected data and output it.

You would run this with `sed -n`:

```
$ sed '=' <file2 | sed -n 'H; ${ x; s/\n//; y/\n/ /; p; }'
1 this is  2  not is  3  is is  4  this biz
```

(no newline at end of output, as there was none at the end of the input).

Alternatively, with an explicit loop we may use `N`.  The trick here is to never reach the end of the script until we're ready to print the result.

```
:top;     # define label 'top'
N;        # append next line with a '\n' embedded
$!btop;   # if not at end, branch to 'top'
y/\n/ /;  # replace all newlines with spaces
          # (implicit print)
```

This script only runs (to the end) once and manages the reading of the data itself whereas the previous script was fed data by the built-in read loop in `sed` (which *replaces the pattern space* for each line read, which was your issue).  It uses the pattern space rather than the hold space to collect the data and processes it when the last line has been read.

On the command line:

```
$ sed '=' <file2 | sed ':top; N; $!btop; y/\n/ /'
```

(same output as above)

Comment: Note that both solutions will store the whole file in memory.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, that's the downside of doing this with sed.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation of the sed command.  Too many people throw out some weird arcane command that works, but makes no sense to 99% of users

Answer (score 3):

If GNU `sed`, try this

```
$ sed -z 's/\n/ /g' file2
this is   not is   is is   this biz
$
```

`tr` does an equally good job.

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' <file2
this is   not is   is is   this biz
$
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I was only curious as to why it is only removing sed inserted newlines?

Comment: `paste -sd" "` is also good at joining lines of a file. As a bonus, it retains the trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally because `sed` is line oriented. What happens is

- sed loads the first line `1` into pattern space
- the `N` command loads the next line, and appends it to pattern space, separated by `\n`, giving `1\nthis is`
- we replace `\n` by space giving `1 this is`

and we're done; the pattern space is printed and then the steps are repeated for each of the remaining (pairs of) lines.

Comment: But what about the new lines I inserted myself using the printf command? Why sed cannot (apparently) recognize them?

Comment: @LinuxNewbie In the `sed` script, you will _never_ see the newlines that are in the original data. The newlines that you substitute are the ones that `N` inserts. The script reads the data line by line and removes the newlines from the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

The command you used only process lines in **pairs**.
The first line is the line number (printed by the `=` command).
The second line is appended to the first, one newline removed, and printed.
Then, the next **pair** of lines is equally processed.

The only way to process **all** lines is to accumulate them until the last line.
At which time, all newlines could be erased/translated to spaces:

```
$ sed '=' file | sed ':start;N;$bend;bstart;:end;y/\n/ /'
1 this is  2  not is  3  is is  4  this biz
```

A shorter line (but also an slower one, which is not a problem with this very short file) is:

```
sed ':1;N;s/\n/ /;t1'
```

Note that both solutions above will store the whole file in memory.

But, of course, `tr` is a better tool for this job:

```
$ sed '=' file | tr '\n' ' '
```

Or, also, `paste` (which retains the trailing newline):

```
$ sed '=' file | paste -sd ' '
1 this is  2  not is  3  is is  4  this biz
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
inputfile

this is
 not is
 is is
```

command:

```
cat inputfile|sed "="| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
1 this is  2  not is  3  is is  4  this biz
```

Comment: This works, but you would have to add as many copies of that `sed` script as there are lines in the file (minus one).